# WinRTXamlCalendar : how to change width?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm working on a Windows 8 app (Windows Store App) and i need to integrate a customisable calendar control.
I need to use free libraries so i'm pretty limited by that.
I digged around the Calendar control of the WinRTXamlToolkit but I couldn't find out a way to expand its width to make it take its parent control's width.

I tried to do basic stuffs such as

```
<c:Calendar Style="{x:Null}" Width="1200"/>
```

or

```
<c:Calendar Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
```

None of those solutions worked...

Is there a way to do so ? Or is there another control that i should be aware of ?

Comment: Have you tried `<c:Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>`? The second won't work unless your MainGrid notifies `PropertyChanged` I don't believe.

Comment: @NateDiamond That was the first thing i tried and obviously it didn't work.. :/

Comment: You may need to create a custom style. The source is available on codeplex, so you can just copy it in and change it how you want.

Comment: @NateDiamond Okay, then i'll do that. That's pretty weird that the component doesn't allow to change its width by itself. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and put the calendar control inside a viewbox element like this.

```
<Viewbox Width="200">
    <xamltk:Calendar IsTodayHighlighted="True" DisplayMode="Month"/>
</Viewbox>
```

A [viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) scales its single child element to the size of the viewbox. Don't forget to set `xamltk` namespace to `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls`.